# Does DocuSign C# Framework SDK have methods for Resend?

Tags: docusignapi

In the UI you can hit a button to resend emails to people who haven't signed.  In the REST API, I found a very poorly documented method to do this same thing  If you PUT to:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts//envelopes//recipients?resend_envelope=true

and include a body like:

```
{
  "signers": [
   {
      "recipientId": "3",
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know if this same functionality is in the C# SDK?  I can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the following obeys the standard rules for resending notifications.

- Notifications will not be delivered for Captive/Embedded Recipients
- Notifications will not be delivered if the recipient's preferences suppress them
- Notifications will only be delivered if the recipient has an active role on the envelope's routing order
- - Notifications will not be delivered to a signer who has already completed their role
- - Notifications will not be delivered to a signer when it is not yet their turn to sign

To resend an envelope to all active recipients:

- Create an Envelope Update Options object with resendEnvelope = true
- Create an empty Envelope object so that the UpdateEnvelope call does not attempt to change any of the envelope's existing parameters
- Execute the Update method against the envelope ID, using the empty Envelope object and the Update Options parameter.

  ```
      EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
      string envelopeGuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";

      EnvelopesApi.UpdateOptions envelopeOptions = new EnvelopesApi.UpdateOptions();
      envelopeOptions.resendEnvelope = "true";
      Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
      envelopesApi.Update(accountId, envelopeGuid, envelope, envelopeOptions);
  ```

To resend an envelope to a specific recipient:

- Create a Recipients Options object with resendEnvelope = true
- Create a recipients list and populate it with the ListRecipients reponse for the envelope
- Select the recipient(s) you would like to resend the envelope to
- - This example selects a single Signer, but can be adapted to include multiple signers, or other recipient types
- Execute the UpdateRecipients method against the envelope ID, using the appropriate list of recipients
- - If multiple recipients are included, it is possible to have a partial success with some failures
- - For example: if you include the list of all recipients, but one signer has already completed their role. Other signers will return 'Sucess' but the completed signer will return an error "The recipient could not be updated. Recipient not in state that allows correction".
- This example hard-codes the first signer

  ```
      string envelopeGuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
      Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
      recipients = envelopesApi.ListRecipients(accountId, envelopeGuid); //get all signers on envelope

      Signer signer = new Signer();
      signer = recipients.Signers[0]; //Replace with logic to select appropriate signer(s)
      Recipients resendRecipients = new Recipients();
      resendRecipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
      resendRecipients.Signers.Add(signer);
      //Add any additional recipients here

      EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsOptions recipientsOptions = new EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsOptions();
      recipientsOptions.resendEnvelope = "true";
      envelopesApi.UpdateRecipients(accountId, envelopeGuid, resendRecipients, recipientsOptions);
  ```